# Display Time Based Gannt charts using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, charts

We are using fusion charts for time based gantt charts. But these charts are not getting displayed as they require flash plug-in which is not supproted by iPhone. So I'm looking for pure javascript charts to get the same type of charts but I have not found any!

I would appreciate if you can point me to right direction. If there are no such links then ,please let me know  how we can create these type of charts using JS.

I'm looking for following type of charts

http://www.fusioncharts.com/widgets/Gallery/Gantt11.html?width=650&height=490

Thanks,
Hari

Answer (score 2):

Good options are DHTMLxGantt, Ext Gantt, EJS TreeGrid and JsGantt.

Disclaimer, I'm the author of Ext Gantt.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this [document](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/standard-charts/gantt-chart#create-time-based-charts), hope it will help you out

Reference code-

```
    FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var timeShiftChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'gantt',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '650',
    height: '400',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
      "chart": {
        "theme": "fusion",
        "dateformat": "dd/mm/yyyy",
        "outputdateformat": "hh12:mn ampm",
        "caption": "Development Division - Time Shifts",
        "canvasBorderAlpha": "30",

        //Enabling Scroll
        "ganttPaneDuration": "12",
        "ganttPaneDurationUnit": "h",
        "scrollToDate": "09:00:00",

        "theme": "fusion"
      },
      "categories": [{
          "category": [{
            "start": "00:00:00",
            "end": "23:59:59",
            "label": "Time"
          }]
        },
        {
          "align": "left",
          "category": [{
              "start": "00:00:00",
              "end": "02:59:59",
              "label": "Midnight"
            },
            {
              "start": "03:00:00",
              "end": "05:59:59",
              "label": "3 am"
            },
            {
              "start": "06:00:00",
              "end": "08:59:59",
              "label": "6 am"
            },
            {
              "start": "09:00:00",
              "end": "11:59:59",
              "label": "9 am"
            },
            {
              "start": "12:00:00",
              "end": "14:59:59",
              "label": "12 noon"
            },
            {
              "start": "15:00:00",
              "end": "17:59:59",
              "label": "3 pm"
            },
            {
              "start": "18:00:00",
              "end": "20:59:59",
              "label": "6 pm"
            },
            {
              "start": "21:00:00",
              "end": "23:59:59",
              "label": "9 pm"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "processes": {
        "fontsize": "12",
        "isbold": "1",
        "align": "left",
        "headertext": "Employee",
        "headerfontsize": "14",
        "headervalign": "middle",
        "headeralign": "left",
        "process": [{
            "label": "John S.",
            "id": "EMP121"
          },
          {
            "label": "David G.",
            "id": "EMP122"
          },
          {
            "label": "Mary P.",
            "id": "EMP123"
          },
          {
            "label": "Andrew H.",
            "id": "EMP124"
          },
          {
            "label": "Neil M.",
            "id": "EMP125"
          }
        ]
      },
      "tasks": {
        "showlabels": "1",
        "task": [{
            "processid": "EMP121",
            "start": "08:00:00",
            "end": "12:30:00",
            "label": "Morning Shift"
          },
          {
            "processid": "EMP121",
            "start": "15:00:00",
            "end": "19:30:00",
            "label": "Evening Shift"
          },
          {
            "processid": "EMP122",
            "start": "10:00:00",
            "end": "16:30:00",
            "label": "Half Day"
          },
          {
            "processid": "EMP123",
            "start": "08:00:00",
            "end": "12:00:00",
            "label": "Morning Shift"
          },
          {
            "processid": "EMP123",
            "start": "15:00:00",
            "end": "21:30:00",
            "label": "Evening Shift"
          },
          {
            "processid": "EMP124",
            "start": "08:00:00",
            "end": "20:30:00",
            "label": "Full time support"
          },
          {
            "processid": "EMP125",
            "start": "10:00:00",
            "end": "14:30:00",
            "label": "Half Day"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }).render();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/6tcmp7oq/)

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76329071/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).